# Trabalhando Erro Volley Android

Tags: android, mobile, volley

Estou criando uma aplicação para Android que envia via Volley algumas strings.
Gostaria de saber como trabalho os erros, por exemplo, caso o servidor esteja offline.

Segue o código referente ao envio das strings:

private void salvarNaWeb(final Usuario objUsuario) {

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_SALVAR_USUARIOWEB,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();


            params.put("nome", objUsuario.getNome());
            params.put("email", objUsuario.getEmail());
            params.put("telefone", objUsuario.getTelefone());
            params.put("senha", objUsuario.getSenha());
            params.put("latitude", latitude + "");
            params.put("longitude", longitude + "");

            mudarTela();
            return params;
        }
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            AppBoloNaHora.WEB_SERVICE_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Gostaria de fazer uma validação, para saber se os dados foram realmente enviados.Pois estou fazendo apenas uma verificação se o celular está com internet para validar o envio/ inserção dos dados no banco de dados.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você precisa obter o NetworkResponse para saber qual o tipo de erro que foi causado.

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          NetworkResponse error_code = error.networkResponse;

          if(error_code == null){
               // Sem conexão a internet no aparelho
               funcaoErroSemInternet();
          }else{
               // Sem conexão ao servidor
               funcaoServidorOffline();
          }
      }
}
```